# Nativescript - Onesignal rest Api

Tags: nativescript, onesignal

I have push notifications on my app with onesignal sdk, but i´m having dificulty understanding how could i send with a large icon, i mean the one that stays on the left when the user receives the push(instead of showing a bell)...i know the icon must be transparent and have 256px x 256px. I´m sending the push using the rest api, but i don´t know where the problem is because nothing seems to work, here is my code:

```
public function sendMessage($messagePush){
        $subtitle=["en" => $messagePush['message']];
        $content      = array(
            "en" => $messagePush['contentJson']['tipoImovel'],
            "large_icon" => public_path('img/icon.png')
        );
        $hashes_array = array();
        array_push($hashes_array, array(
            "id" => "id1",
            "text" => "Ver"
        ));
        $fields = array(
            'app_id' => "myappid",
            'included_segments' => array(
                'All'
            ),
            'data' => array(
                "imovel" => $messagePush['contentJson']
            ),
            'headings'=> $subtitle,
            'contents' => $content,
            'buttons' => $hashes_array
        );

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization: my autorization'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $resp;
    }
```

I can receive the push, but the icon never appears, and there´s also another problem...the push always appear on the top tray instead of the popup "kind", for that manner below is also my code that is on my app.js:

```
if (application.android) {
    application.on(application.launchEvent, (args) => {
        try {
            TnsOneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new TnsOneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler({
                // notificationOpened: function (result: com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult) {
                notificationOpened: function (result) {
                    const imovelAndroid =  JSON.parse(result.stringify()).notification.payload.additionalData;
                    handleOpenURL(imovelAndroid);
                }
            })).init();
            TnsOneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(TnsOneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
            TnsOneSignal.startInit(application.android.context).init();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('error', error);
        }
    });
}
```

If i remove the **TnsOneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(TnsOneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);** the popup style appears, but the buttons don´t navegate to my **handleOpenURL** function...but if i let it stay, it does navigate but the push is always on the tray.

Any tips? thanks for your time.
Regards

Comment: I'm not sure why you have two `startInit` statements with different parameters. You could remove the second `startInit` statement and move the `setInFocusDisplaying` method call above the first `startInit`. Lets know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hey Manoj, what about my other issue? any tips?

Comment: You will have to remove `TnsOneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(TnsOneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);` as that would force the notification to be the tray one. Default one is `InAppAlert` already. You were resetting `setNotificationOpenedHandler` on second call to `startInit`. So if you adjust it as I mentioned above, I hope it should work.

Comment: That´s it!!! thank you so much Manoj! it´s working, i still have the problem with the icons but now the push appears like popup instead of tray, and when i it the button it goes directly to the detail view as i wanted...if you know how to put the icons please!!! tell me...don´t forget to answer the question so that i set it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to remove `TnsOneSignal.setInFocusDisplaying(TnsOneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);` as that would force the notification to be the tray one. Default one is `InAppAlert` already.

You were resetting `setNotificationOpenedHandler` on second call to `startInit`. So if you remove the second `startInit` statement too you should be good.